# How to set the type of the collection in typescript and meteor.js?

Tags: typescript, meteor, meteor-react

I’m really new to typescript and wonder how to set a type to a collection.

This is my part of the react component. I need to pull a user document from Users collection.

```
const user = useTracker(() => Users.find({_id: userId}).fetch(), [userId]);
```

I have a `Cannot find name 'Users'. Did you mean 'user'?` error on my code editor.

I didn’t not mean to type `user`, the collection name is the `Users`.

The thing is the Users collection file is written in `js` not `tsx`.

Is there a way to define a type of the Users collection?

Comment: You don't need to set a type. But I also don't think the error you are showing is thrown by the code you are showing. Is there another place where you use `'Users'` (as a string i mean)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this method:

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import { UserType } from "/imports/types/users";

const Users: Mongo.Collection<UserType> = Meteor.users;

export default Users;
```